# .tsx component Button onclick event shows undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx, react-tsx

I create a .tsx component and a function that is returning dynamic HTML.

```
   getCellValues(_data) {
    var ret=`<div onClick="`+this.selectDate("1")+`">1</div>`;
     console.log(ret)
     return ret; }
```

and this select data function looks like

```
 selectDate(_data: string) {
     console.log("*****selectDate**************************");
     console.log(_data); }
```

and in component constructor added this line of code.

```
this.selectDate = this.selectDate.bind(this);
```

but after loading component this div onclick event shows undefined... ANd the rendered html looks like..

```
<div onclick="undefined">1</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply return the JSX:

```js
getCellValues(_data) {
  return <div onClick={() => this.selectDate(1)}>1</div>
};
```

Comment: i cant return like this because i am having a complete dynamic html block and this div is the part of that html block

Comment: I see. I don't know the fix for this, but ideally, you'd refactor the code so it's not using dynamic HTML this way. The point of using React kind of evaporates.

Comment: actually i am creating a dynamic calender so i have to use dynamic html

Comment: How so? I'd gladly look into a snippet, but I doubt it's not refactorable into generic JSX components.

Comment: Its not possible for me to upload complete snippet here... i have a calender with all dates should be clickable event.. and for that i want this button click event which is currently undefined